# SSRS - one particular report refuses to be saved as Excel or CSV

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have one, only one, report that won't download. This symptom arose just this week.  There have been no changes to the report or to the configuration of the report server.

When the report completes (after >= 20 minutes), the user clicks the Save icon and chooses a file type.  The server quickly responds with a page containing only the following (inside my dashes):

---

Reporting Services Error
For more information about this error navigate to the report server on the local server machine, or enable remote errors
SQL Server Reporting Services

---

I haven't been able to find anything on this site or MS site (of course) or elsewhere that offers anything more than instructions on turning on logging and finding the logs folder.  I have logging set to ON and I can't find any recent log on the server.

Anybody seen this before?
Thanks.

I tried saving a copy of the affected report.  It contains two tablixes, with a parameter to toggle visibility.  My user wants to download the contents of the Detail tablix.  So, in my copy I deleted the Summary tablix.  This did not solve the error.

Comment: I have never seen this before but, once the report is completed in the web portal and you export the report, the cached data is rendered by the server into the selected file type. It could be that the server is low resource but that's just a guess. The first things I would do, if possible, is to restart the SSRS service and if that does not help, restart the server that SSRS is running on. If you open the report in Visual Studio, does it render to Excel OK then?

Comment: Restarting the SSRS service resolved the problem.  I did not restart the server.  Thank you, Alan.

Comment: Well that was a lucky guess! Glad you got it sorted...